# Optimistic Concurrency Failure with Lucene on App Engine/Datastore

Tags: java, google-app-engine, lucene, google-cloud-datastore

I am using Lucene with Datastore/App Engine and when I try to purge the indexes, I get an Optimistic Concurrency error:

`com.googlecode.objectify.impl.TransactorNo transactNew: Optimistic concurrency failure for com.googlecode.luceneappengine.GaeLockFactory$1$1@17fcdba (retrying): java.util.ConcurrentModificationException: too much contention on these datastore entities. please try again.`

I am unable to retrive new indexed data unless I manually delete the Lucene Index entities from datastore and reindex the data. Has anyone had any similar issues?

Code:

```
public int purgeIndex() {
    int numDocs = 0;
    try (GaeDirectory directory = new GaeDirectory(indexName); Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer()) {

        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

        IndexWriterConfig indexWriterConfig = getIndexWriterConfig(LUCENE_VERSION, analyzer);
        indexWriterConfig.setOpenMode(IndexWriterConfig.OpenMode.APPEND);

        try (IndexWriter w = new IndexWriter(directory, indexWriterConfig)) {
            w.deleteAll();
            w.commit();
            numDocs = w.numDocs();
            LOG.info("index: all deleted, remaining {} indexed. ", w.numDocs());
            w.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.error("Error purge content", e);
        }
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        LOG.info("purgeIndex: {} millis. ", end - start);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        LOG.error("Error purge", e);
    }
    return numDocs;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Stu have you considered using the built in search API?